# Not a single angular directive working in this code.The function define in submit button does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have tried many angular directive in this code but none of them is 
          working. Is there any library file is missing or something wrong in 
          this code  or is there any effect due to jQuery file.
           The complete code is define below:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ticketcontroller">

<head>
    <title>Ticket</title>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css"
    type="text/css" media="screen" property=""
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css"
    type="text/css" media="screen" property=""
    />
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700"
    rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Ticket Details Forum</h1>

        <div class="w3_agile_main_grids">
            <section class="slider">
                <div class="flexslider">

                    <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_grid">
                        <h3>Service Details</h3>
                        <form>
                            <span>
                                         <label>Category</label>
                                         <select  required="" ng-
                                          model="service">
                                             <option value="">Laptop 
                                            Repair</option>
                                             <option value="">Refrigerator 
                                             repair</option>
                                             <option value="">Microwave 
                                                  repair</option>


                                         </select>
                                     </span>
                            <span>
                                         <label>Priority</label>
                                         <select  required="" ng-
                                           model="priority">
                                             <option value="">Low</option>
                                             <option 
                                          value="">Normal</option>         
                                             <option value="">High</option>

                                         </select>
                                     </span>

                            <span>
                                         <label>Description</label>
                                        <input name="description" 
    type="text" placeholder="Enter Description here" ng-model="description">
                                     </span>

                            <div class="w3_agileits_submit">

                                <button class="btn btn-success" ng- click="submitdata()">submit</button>

                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
            </section>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- flexSlider -->
        <script defer src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
                $('.flexslider')
                    .flexslider({
                        animation: "slide",
                        start: function(
                            slider
                        ) {
                            $
                                (
                                    'body'
                                )
                                .removeClass(
                                    'loading'
                                );
                        }
                    });
            });
        </script>

</body>

</html>

<script>
    var ap = angular.module("myapp", []);
    ap.controller("ticketcontroller", [
                '$scope', '$http',
                '$window',
                function($scope, $http,
                    $window) {
                    $scope.submitdata =
                        function() {
                            $window.alert(
                                "dhbhhfgh);
                            }
                        }]);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you put your angular code in your head section that is above the html body and see if it is working?

Comment: what is console output?

Comment: I think your angular code that you have placed below the html tag is being executed after the body is rendered. This will make all the angular instance in your body not to execute properly.

Comment: You have missed to close the string here  `$window.alert("dhbhhfgh);` change it to `$window.alert("dhbhhfgh");`

Comment: @XYZ he doesn´t even need the $window. Into javascript, with "alert()" is enough

Comment: @FooBar correct

Answer (score 0):

Corrected just with the angular directive, add flexslider later.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<title>Ticket</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="controllers.js"></script>-->
    <!--this (under) should be into controllers.js-->
    <script>
      var apk = angular.module('myapp', []);    
  apk.controller("ticketcontroller",function($scope,$http,$window){
      var service;
      var priority;
      var description;
   $scope.submitdata=function(){
            var vm = this;
            service = vm.service;
            priority = vm.priority;
            description = vm.description;
            alert("this is my desc: /"+service+"/ with priority: /"+priority+"/ and description: /"+description+"/");
   }
  });
  </script>
  <!-- I REMOVED ALL FLEXSLIDER FROM THIS CODE PUT IT BACK -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  </script>
 </head>
 <body  ng-controller="ticketcontroller" >
            <div class="main">
            <h1>Ticket Details Forum</h1>

            <div class="w3_agile_main_grids">
            <section class="slider">
            <div class="flexslider">

            <div class="agileits_w3layouts_main_grid">
            <h3>Service Details</h3>
            <form action="#">
            <span>
            <label>Category</label>
            <select  required="" ng-model="service">
            <option>Laptop Repair</option>
            <option>Refrigerator repair</option>
            <option>Microwave repair</option>
            </select>
            </span>
            <span>
            <label>Priority</label>
            <select  required="" ng-model="priority">
            <option>Low</option>
            <option>Normal</option>         
            <option>High</option>
              <!-- BE AWARE, I REMOVED VALUE FROM OPTION IN CONTROLLER -->
            </select>
            </span>
            <span>
            <label>Description</label>
            <input name="description" type="text" placeholder="Enter Description here" ng-model="description"> </input>
            </span>

            <div class="w3_agileits_submit">
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitdata()">submit</button>
            </div>
            </form>
                </div>
                </section>
                </div>
                </div>
        </body>
  </html>
```

works like a charm. Copy paste and try, remember you had different script-links, update mine to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Try to name your controller in a CamelCase style.